# How to change animation in highcharts for pie point selection?

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, charts, highcharts

Is there any way to change animation on click to pie point? By default (you can see that pie point is taken from chart with distance from others):

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'pie'
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        allowPointSelect: true
    }
},
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5r86cn74/1/

[image]

I need to find solution to do sth like that (just to lengthen it, not take all point outside of the pie):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really easy to achieve in Highcharts. You can just use point's `click` event, change `r` property and store the selected state.

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    data: [...],
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function() {
          const offset = 20;

          this.graphic.animate({
            r: this.shapeArgs.r + (this.customSelect ? 0 : offset)
          });

          this.customSelect = !this.customSelect;
        }
      }
    }
  }]
});

document.getElementById('getSelected').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const selectedPoints = chart.series[0].points.filter(point => point.customSelect);

  console.log(selectedPoints);
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3c2xhmyg/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#animate

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie